# $http finally block not running in AngularJS 1.4

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get some JS code to run after clicking on a radio button, using AngularJS 1.4.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="future"
ng-change="requestReses(jsonStatus, '', jsonCheckedUserNotYetRun)"
ng-model="jsonStatus">
```

JS:

```
$scope.requestReses = function(requestStatus, requestTimeline,
requestCheckedUser) {
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'handlers/res/find',
  data: {
    status: requestStatus,
    timeline: requestTimeline,
    checked_user: requestCheckedUser
  }
};

$http(req).then(function(response) {
  $scope.reses = response.data.entries;
  $scope.error = response.data.error;
}, function(response) {
  $scope.error = 'Could not connect to the server';
}).finally(function() {
  $scope.numberOfPages = Math.floor(($scope.reses.length - 1)/ 20) + 1;
  $scope.changePage(1);
});
};
```

The success function runs, but the finally function doesn't. Additionally, $scope.reses isn't updated outside of the scope of the success function.

Comment: Any errors in your console? You should try debugging and add some breakpoints in your `then` and `finally` callbacks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/nKzN7mWoPHV6m3hlodCu?p=preview

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. If I add a console.log statement at the end of the finally callback, it's not run because only the first of the statements gets executed. The same happens when I comment out the first statement.